# Rails 4 - uninitialized constant SessionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm working on a Rails app in which I have a Session controller with the following method:

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Utloggad"
end
```

In my routes file I have the following routes:

```
controller :session do
  get 'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

And my view looks like this:

```
= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete, :class => "small"
```

When I press the link I get the following error: `uninitialized constant SessionController`. How can I solve this?

Comment: paste the code of your `SessionController`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without your code I can't be sure but if you are using devise it should probably be `SessionsController` and not `SessionController`
so your code should look like

```
controller :sessions do
  get 'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Yes, it was Sessions (not using Devise though).